# How can I stop being ambushed by mummies?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

I find that I am always ambushed by mummies and my heroes keep getting scared and running away.

Is there a certain outfit colour that makes this more or less likely? Or is this completely random?

Comment: I believe it is completley random and very annoying aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Shadowmathfreak's FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/faqs/63604), "The mummy will scare off the first hero in line unless the Mii’s color is the same as the mummy." **So to stop being ambushed by the mummy, your first hero that the mummy encounters needs to be the same colour as the mummy in question.** In the case of a bright/dark/etc room with a mummy, you need to clear the room's obstruction first and the hero right after will need to be the same colour as the mummy to avoid being scared away.

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate. I have had cases where a blue mummy scared off a level 7 blue hero and where a red mummy scared off a level 7 red hero.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I would ask for proof - are you sure they were the same colour? It's not really my info to defend (it's the FAQs) so I'm doing a run through myself to test anyways. It may only apply to Shambling/Roaming mummies as the FAQ becomes less descriptive of later mummies.

Comment: I think it was Shambling/Roaming mummies. They looked like the same color as my heroes, so I assumed that that was what the answer was referring to.

Answer (score 3):

If a mummy is in the room, then it has a chance to scare off the first hero in line so that they don't get a turn.  This occurs before the hero gets any action - including "Return" or "Team Up".

Higher-level heroes seem to be a little less susceptible to this.  A level 5 hero has shrugged off the ambush, and been able to take his turn.

When you're spending Play Coins to hire heroes, and facing a mummy, you can mitigate the mummy's ambush by putting a cheap Wandering Hero up front.  The Wandering Hero may be frighted, but everyone else in your party will get a chance to do some damage.  But don't buy a Wandering Hero in anticipation of getting some Street Pass connections later and then leave the game - I did this and the Wandering Hero vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, my brown Mii has been able to shrug off ambushes from Marauding Mummies every single time. Against other types, I haven't had much luck. In that case, just hiring a Wandering Hero decoy is helpful, or maybe some other color works.